# Using UIAlertController to call its containing function

Tags: objective-c

I am using `Reachability` to check for any change in wifi connectivity. This sets the variable `wifiStatus` to either Y or N depending on the connection. This is working fine.

When the app starts I have a function called `setup` which calls itself until wifiStatus is Y.

```
- (void)setup {
    if([wifiStatus isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
        //go to another function;
    }
    else {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Wifi" message:@"You must be connected to the internet to complete set up." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Try again" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            [self setup];
        }];
        [alert addAction:alertAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

It works perfectly well I am just checking that I am not going to run into any sort of recursion issues if the user has to press `Try again` a number of times.

Comment: Nope, that should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Excellent - thank you.